# Packages Installing in PyCharm

Tags: python, git, pycharm, anaconda

I'm quite new to PyCharm IDE so have a question about installing the packages for my project.

Basically, I had already installed Anaconda (4.4.0) with Python 3.6 on the board and all related packages and libraries.

When I clone Python project from Git repo to PyCharm, the message then displays that I need to install the requirement packages and when I'm trying to do so I receive an error message:

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.6*
  - scipy ==0.15.1 -> python 2.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Seems something about conflict Python 2.6 and Anaconda's Python 3.6

Do you know how can I manage this thing and bring it to life?

Thanks!

Comment: is PyCharm using Python 3.6 interpreter? Show us project setup.py file.

Comment: Yep, using 3.6 as interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all conda commands in [conda documentation](https://conda.io/docs/commands.html#conda-general-commands).

For this particular case you can try:

```
conda update --all
```

However, it is not possible to give an exact answer without seeing `setup.py` file of project.

Answer (score 0):

`Python 3.6` is not fully update all packages . It is more better use  `Python 3.5`

For Python you can use it in command interpreter  ....

`pip install 'your desire package name'`

For Anaconda ...

`conda install 'your desire package name'`